# How to gracefully exit a loop in .net VB

Tags: vb.net, loops

I have this loop which opens random files and sequentially reads from these files. Since these files could be literally in the thousands I need a way to exit the for and do loop without the system hanging as it now does when the stop search button is clicked.

Currently the best method I have found to use is to set the x loop to the last number when the stop search button is clicked.

I have tried to exit both the loop with exit for and exit do but these made no difference to why the system hangs for a while before the system can stop the loop. I have to click a few times on the stop search button before the program becomes responsive.
Below is part of the code that’s does the loop :-

> ```
> Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
>     Button1.Click
>
>     stopsearch = False
>
>     Dim x As Single
>
>     Dim startvalue As Single
>     Dim endvalue As Single
>
>
>     startvalue = Val(TextBox1.Text)
>     endvalue = Val(TextBox2.Text)
>
>
>
>     If TextBox4.Text <> "" Then
>
>
>         ListView1.Items.Clear()
>
>         ProgressBar1.Minimum = startvalue
>         ProgressBar1.Maximum = endvalue
>
>         Button1.Text = "Searching . . . "
>
>         For x = startvalue To endvalue
>             ProgressBar1.Value = x
>             Dim f As String
>
>             If stopsearch = True Then
>                 x = endvalue
>                   exit for
>             End If
>
>
>             f = TextBox3.Text + "-" + Trim(Str(x)) + "." + company
>
>             If File.Exists(D_Drive + "\STORE-16\" + f) Then
>
>                 'MsgBox(f)
>
>                 FileClose(30)
>                 FileOpen(30, D_Drive + "\store-16\" + f, OpenMode.Input)
>
>
>                 Try
>                     Dim sr As String = ""
>                     Do While Not EOF(30)
>                         sr = LineInput(30)
>
>
>                         If InStr(UCase(sr), UCase(TextBox4.Text)) > 0 Then
>
>                             Dim i As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(Str(x))
>                             i.SubItems.Add(sr)
>                             Application.DoEvents()
>
>                         End If
>                     Loop
>                 Finally
>                     FileClose(30)
>                 End Try
>
>             End If
>
>
>         Next x
>
>         Button1.Text = "Re-start Search "
>
>     End If
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
>     stopsearch = True
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: `these made no difference to why the system hangs for a while before the system can stop the loop` quit calling `DoEvents`, don't update the progress bar in the loop and some others, but this isn't code review. To get out of the loop just call `Exit For`... Just setting a variable doesnt exit the loop that's why because it's still going.

Comment: On another note `vb6 <> vb.net`... In your code you reference a lot of it. I would recommend ripping it out and use the newer .net functions and methods...

Comment: Zaggler thanks for the comments - I have inserted Exit For an even tried tried not to update the progress bar . . .

I can't help myself but to use vb6 code - if only someone could transform my code with newer .net functions and methods so that I could learn . . I have no clue when looking at this code where to begin implementing . . .

Comment: @BASitBulbulia, Remove reference of `Microsoft.VisualBasic` from your project and you will start learning straight away

Comment: Use [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) for updating `ProgressBar` and button's text while reading the files. Or learn using `async/await` methods they were designed exactly for this purpose

Comment: I have tried all of the above ! Nothing stop's the hanging . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some further research I discovered that if I enclosed my code in a thread I could flawlessly stop the loop (suspend the thread).

If you using the thread the way I have ; it's preferable that on loading of the form you have the following code :-

```
 Private Sub LaybuyInputDialog_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Me.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

    End Sub
```

Also don't forget to insert **Imports.System.Threading** on top of form.

For the sake of someone new to threading below is the code I changed :-

```
  Dim thread As System.Threading.Thread



    Private Sub DoSearch()

        Button1.Hide()

        stopsearch = False

        Dim x As Single

        Dim startvalue As Single
        Dim endvalue As Single


        startvalue = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        endvalue = Val(TextBox2.Text)



        If TextBox4.Text <> "" Then


            ListView1.Items.Clear()

            ProgressBar1.Minimum = startvalue
            ProgressBar1.Maximum = endvalue

            Button1.Text = "Searching . . . "

            For x = startvalue To endvalue
                ProgressBar1.Value = x
                Dim f As String

                If stopsearch = True Then
                    x = endvalue
                    Exit For
                End If



                f = TextBox3.Text + "-" + Trim(Str(x)) + "." + company

                If File.Exists(D_Drive + "\STORE-16\" + f) Then

                    'MsgBox(f)

                    FileClose(30)
                    FileOpen(30, D_Drive + "\store-16\" + f, OpenMode.Input)


                    Try
                        Dim sr As String = ""
                        Do While Not EOF(30)
                            sr = LineInput(30)

                            If stopsearch = True Then
                                x = endvalue
                                Exit Do
                            End If

                            If InStr(UCase(sr), UCase(TextBox4.Text)) > 0 Then

                                Dim i As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(Str(x))
                                i.SubItems.Add(sr)
                                If ListView1.Items.Count > 0 Then
                                    ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).EnsureVisible()
                                End If
                                Application.DoEvents()

                            End If
                        Loop
                    Finally
                        FileClose(30)
                    End Try

                End If


            Next x

            Button1.Text = "Re-start Search "

        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf DoSearch)
        thread.Start()


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        stopsearch = True
        Try
            thread.Suspend()
        Catch ex As Exception
            '
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Hope my answer helps someone; please feel free to comment if you do have a better solution ! !